# Getting answers for an unregistered user's question

Tags: discussion

So there's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181011/host-wcf-service-with-net-tcp-binding-through-iis-manager-7-5#) that is basically identical to what I need answered, but it was never fully answered.  The question was posted by an unregistered user.  I'd like to add an incentive for getting that question answered, so I'm considering offering bounty.  However, this scenario doesn't quite work right, because:

1. If I need to provide any additional information to help with the question, I would then have to either enter comments (not ideal for long content) or edit the OP's question (not ideal because it would be additional information about *my* setup, not the OP's).
2. The OP would need to accept the answer in order to award the bounty (unless I was lucky enough to have upvotes mirror my intended result).  Since the user is not registered, they might not even have the ability or incentive to accept an answer.

Another option would be for me to post another question.  Although this would allow me to post specific details relating to *my* problem, the question would probably be closed as a duplicate of the older question.

I wish I could just take ownership of this potentially orphaned question, but since I can't, what is the most acceptable action for someone in my situation to take?

Comment: can you explain why placing your own bounty with a custom message would not work?

Comment: also not following why the op would need to accept? you can still award a bounty

Comment: There's no good place to place follow-up communication (i.e. additional configuration details for *my* setup)

Comment: @waffles, bounty can be awarded by the bounty offerer?  I thought bounty was awarded to the accepted answer.  If that's not the case, then #2 is not a concern.

Comment: **yes** the bounty system is totally decoupled from accepted answers or votes. Only place where voting is taken in consideration is when the system awards the bounty on your behalf (since you forgot or did not award the bounty on time)

Comment: Can you start by editing the question into something more coherent, without losing any information? I think that is a great first step, the current question is confusing.

Comment: Very cool.  Concern #1 still remains, though.  I'm sure that in most scenarios, comments would suffice, but if I needed to post something like WCF configuration XML, it would not.

Answer (score 2):

The OP hasn't been back for two months, since a week after the question was posted. Good for you for wanting to avoid duplicates. Throw down a bounty and just **edit that sucker**. Since the current answers are *extremely* general, nothing should be lost, and probably value will be gained, by adding specifics, even if they perhaps did not apply to the OP.